# Accessing value from another slice

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Hello I am using Redux Toolkit. I would like to access values from another slice in another slice. Or it is just more convenient to stay in one big slice?

first slice

```
 const INITIAL_VALUE = {
      recipes: [] as Recipe[],
      filteredRecipes: [] as Recipe[],
      likedRecipes: {
        recipes: [] as Recipe[],
        totalAmount: 0,
      },
      recipeTypes: ["Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner", "Supper"], // tutaj dodaj czas i typy
      recipeTime: [
        "Very short (~30min)",
        "short (~1hr)",
        "medium (~3hrs)",
        "Long (~6hrs)",
      ],
    };

second slice
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  filteredRecipes = Recipes[]
};


const secondSlice = createSlice({
  name: "ui",
  initialState: INITIAL_STATE,
  reducers: {
    filterItems(state, action) {
state.filteredRecipes = recipes.filter(recipe => ???) // I want to access recipes from the first slice.
  },
});
```

Comment: `INITIAL_VALUE ` is not used at all in this snippet. Is there a typo or syntax error maybe?

Comment: It looks like what's happening in your app is that someone sets a filter in the UI and then the list of recipes gets filtered by some criteria? In this case it's better to not filter in redux. State should be atomic and without duplication. I'd save the filter criteria somewhere in the state (for example 'alphabetical' or 'chronological') and then the filtered recipes are computed in a selector.

Comment: Okay i understand. Timotgl I did not put createSlice logic in the first example because it seemed useless in this snippet.

Comment: In any case "recipes" and "filteredRecipes" seem so closely related that I'd keep them in the same slice.

Comment: Okay timotgl thanks for an advice I am beginner and that is great I learnt something new. I need to filter recipes in selector and it is not good to put it inside slice yeah?

Comment: It seemed to me easier to put filtered recipes inside Redux because accessing values across entire app is quite confusing.

Comment: Yes, if "filteredRecipes" is just a subset of "recipes" i'd say it's better to not copy those array elements, but rather re-compute the filtered version on demand. Libraries like reselect help with memoization/caching so that any expensive computation doesn't happen more often than needed.

Comment: You would simply always go through the selector instead of accessing the state directly, this is the philosophy behind redux as far as I know it.

Comment: So what I think about now. I should create variables in slice like title, type, time and then use these variables to filter recipes in selector.

Comment: Okay sir thank you a lot :)